# CUBRID database

Tags: database, cubrid

I have received a message about CUBRID database they said that it's better than MySQL in performance, so any one heard about it.

Is that correct

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use CUBRID in most of my projects. The idea of being "better than MySQL", I think, depends on the situation, on the needs of your application. For some CUBRID is really nice, for some MySQL, or some other one. For example, CUBRID has very nice features optimized for Social Networking Services where you have heavy traffic often on one page, use lots of indexes, and take advantage of covering index. They provide some nice examples how to design your database schema and how to tune queries to obtain the best performance ([link](http://www.cubrid.org/cubrid_query_tuning)).

What's your case? If you expect simultaneously several hundred users who generate some thousands of new records every day, CUBRID can easily handle all these. This is what database systems are created for.

You should also consider the environment you are developing in. Is your app developed on PHP, Python, or what? We use PHP and Java on our sites. CUBRID has many Drivers. I believe you can find the necessary driver on their site.

You should also look at the community support. If you have some questions or issues with their database, it's often faster to directly write on their [Q&A site](http://www.cubrid.org/questions) or [forum](http://www.cubrid.org/forum).